# PHP - Undefined type "Customer"

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, object, oop

File structure:

- Controllers/Foo.php
- Models/Bar.php
- Models/Functions.php

In Foo.php, using a require_once() I can use functions from Functions.php, but I cannot instantiate the Bar class?
It gives the error `"Undefined type 'App\Controllers\Bar'."`. I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

If it helps, this is in a Codeigniter project, hence why Bar extends Database.

Foo.php

```
require (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '\..\Models\Functions.php');
require (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '\..\Models\Bar.php');

class Foo extends Controller {
    public function get_data($input) {
        $oBar = new Bar() // this is where the error occurs
    }
}
```

Bar.php

```
<?php

class Bar extends Database {
    public function do_something() {
        echo 'something else';
    }
}
```

Functions.php

```
<?php

function say_hi() {
    echo 'hi';
}
```

Comment: Use the linux `/` and not the windows ``\`` even if you are using windows

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried this but now it says "Cannot declare class Database, because the name is already in use". If I change it to Database2 it gives the same error but with Database2. This is really confusing! Sorry I cannot share much of the code, but I have done my best of obfuscating it.

Comment: Are you using *namespaces* because the error says it `'App\Controllers\Bar'`. So if `Bar` is not in a namespace, then use `new \Bar()` to get it work. Maybe you have to do `new \Models\Bar()` but i cant say for real, because related code is missing in your example.

Comment: @Foobar omg you're incredible, I didn't notice the namespaces! Thank you so much that has solved the problem! :D :D Also how do I now mark this as an answer? It doesn't let me :(

Comment: For an *answer* i had do write code. But its just an explantion. I can drop it as Answer, one moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are using namespaces because the error says it `'App\Controllers\Bar'`.

So if Bar is not in a namespace, then use `new \Bar()` to get it work.

Maybe you have to do `new \Models\Bar()` or `new \App\Models\Bar()`
but i can't say for real, because related code is missing in your example.

Comment: this has fixed the problem! Thank you! :)